# Problema al soltar una card(tarea) con drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, jquery-ui

Buenos días estoy haciendo un tablero kanban con html jquery y el problema es que al soltar mi card(tarea) en una columna vacía no me permite soltarlo allí.Solo lo suelta cuando las columnas contienen card(tarea).

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Este ejemplo esta con javascript: index.html y tareas.json

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tablero Kanban</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row" id="board">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">TO DO</div>
          <div class="card-body items todo">
                <!--<div class="card bg-light mb-3 item" id="1">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">DOING</div>
          <div class="card-body items" >
            <div class="card bg-light mb-3 item" id="2">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">TO DO</div>
          <div class="card-body items" >
            <!--<div class="card bg-light mb-3 item" id="3">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.getJSON('tareas.json', function(json) {
            var con=1;
            $.each(json.obj, function(index, val) {
                ++con;
                 var div = $('<div class="card bg-light mb-3 item" id="'+ con+'">'
                    +'<div class="card-body"><p class="card-text">'+json.obj[index].nom
                    +'</p></div></div>');
                 $(".todo").append(div);
            });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
        for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            var card = cards[i];
            card.draggable="true";
            console.log(cards.length);
        }
    });


    var board = document.getElementById("board");
    var hideMe;

    board.onselectstart = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    board.ondragstart = function(e) {
        console.log('dragstart');
        hideMe = e.target;//Me devuelve todo los atributos del div
        console.log(hideMe);
        e.dataTransfer.setData('card', e.target.id);
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    };

    board.ondragend = function(e) {
        e.target.style.visibility = 'visible';
    };

    var lastEneterd;

    board.ondragenter = function(e) {
        console.log('dragenter');
        if (hideMe) {
            hideMe.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            hideMe = null;
        }
        // Save this to check in dragleave.
        lastEntered = e.target;
        var item = closestWithClass(e.target, 'item');
        // TODO: Check that it's not the original section.
        if (item) {
            item.classList.add('droppable');
            e.preventDefault(); // Not sure if these needs to be here. Maybe for IE?
            return false;
        }
    };

    board.ondragover = function(e) {
            // TODO: Check data type.
            // TODO: Check that it's not the original section.
            if (closestWithClass(e.target, 'item')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };

    board.ondragleave = function(e) {
        // FF is raising this event on text nodes so only check elements.
        if (e.target.nodeType === 1) {
            // dragleave for outer elements can trigger after dragenter for inner elements
            // so make sure we're really leaving by checking what we just entered.
            // relatedTarget is missing in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66547
            var item = closestWithClass(e.target, 'item');
            if (item && !item.contains(lastEntered)) {
                item.classList.remove('droppable');
            }
        }
        lastEntered = null; // No need to keep this around.
    };

    board.ondrop = function(e) {
        var item = closestWithClass(e.target, 'items');
        var id = e.dataTransfer.getData('card');
        if (id) {
            var card = document.getElementById(id);
            // Might be a card from another window.
            if (card) {
                if (item !== card.parentNode) {
                    item.appendChild(card);
                }
            } else {
                alert('couldn\'t find card #' + id);
            }
        }
        item.classList.remove('droppable');
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    function closestWithClass(target, className) {
        while (target) {
            if (target.nodeType === 1 &&
                target.classList.contains(className)) {
                return target;
            }
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        return null;
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**tareas.json**

```
{
    "cod":"00",
    "obj":[
        {"codTar":1,"nom":"Realizar Impresion de Entradas","des":"", "res":{"codRes":1,"nom":"Julio"},"est":{"codEst":1}},
        {"codTar":2,"nom":"Realizar Compra de Bebidas","des":"", "res":{"codRes":2,"nom":"Carlos"},"est":{"codEst":2}},
        {"codTar":3,"nom":"Realizar Puffs","des":"", "res":{"codRes":3,"nom":"Alfredo"},"est":{"codEst":1}},
        {"codTar":4,"nom":"Realizar Limpieza del Local","res":{"codRes":4,"nom":"Yessica"},"est":{"codEst":2}},
        {"codTar":5,"nom":"Realizar Publicidad","res":{"codRes":5,"nom":"Rocio"},"est":{"codEst":1}}
    ]
}
```

Ejemplo 02 es con metodo sortable de jquery UI 
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

**ejemplo1.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Portlets</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--<style>
  body {
    min-width: 520px;
  }
  .column {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .portlet {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
  }
  .portlet-header {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }
  .portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  .portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 50px;
  }
  </style>-->
  <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header",
      cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
      placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all"
    });

    $( ".portlet" )
      .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $( ".portlet-toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
      var icon = $( this );
      icon.toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick" );
      icon.closest( ".portlet" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });
  } );
  </script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">TO DO</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="column">    
                <div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3">
                  <div class="portlet-header card-header">Feeds</div>
                  <div class="portlet-content card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3">
                  <div class="portlet-header card-header">News</div>
                  <div class="portlet-content card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>     

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">DOING</div>
            <div class="card-body" >
                <div class="column">    
                  <!--<div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="portlet-header card-header">Shopping</div>
                    <div class="portlet-content card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>-->
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card bg-light mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">END</div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="column">

              <div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3">
                <div class="portlet-header card-header">Links</div>
                <div class="portlet-content card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3">
                <div class="portlet-header card-header">Images</div>
                <div class="portlet-content card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
                </div>
              </div>     
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*$.getJSON('tareas.json', function(json) {
      $.each(json.obj, function(index, val) {
         var div = $('<div class="portlet card bg-light mb-3"><div class="portlet-header card-header">Links</div>'
          +'<div class="portlet-content card-body"><p class="card-text">'+json.obj[index].nom
          +'</p></div></div>');
         $(".column").append(div);
      });
  });*/
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno encontré el problema era la funcion closestWithClass(e.target, 'item')  la cual no permitía soltar el elemento si no encontraba el target.

```
board.ondragover = function(e) {
                // TODO: Check data type.
                // TODO: Check that it's not the original section.
                //if (closestWithClass(e.target, 'item')) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                //}
            };
```